# Trying to find Derailleur hanger for Triace A310

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur, derailleur-rear

As you can figure out from a quick google search, this bike almost does not exist. Finding info for this bike has been near impossible. If you can direct me to any info about which hanger I need to replace my broken rear derailleur hanger, that would be awesome.

Comment: Pictures would help a lot.

Comment: Odds are pretty good that it's a standard hanger.  While there are dozens of variations, 99% of applications are covered by 2-3 different styles.

Answer (score 1):

While the Triace A310 is an entry level bike I wouldn't put it in the same class as a Walmart  BSO (bicycle shaped object). It doesn't appear to be a bike brand common to the U.S. Your best bet would be to remove the hanger and take it to your local bike shop. Most shops have a wall chart that has full size photos of the 50-60 most common types. You match yours' to the example and they can order you a #46 hanger or what ever number is appropriate. If it is one of the less common type that they don't stock you may want to order two so you have a spare.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Triace is a BSO (Walmart bike). I'm surprised one would have a replacable derailleur hanger.

If it does have a removable derailleur hanger, you're likely going to have try a [generic derailleur hanger](http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers.html) (disclaimer: no affiliation, never bought from them) or if it had quick release (unlikely), something like [Problem Solvers' Universal Derailleur Hanger](http://problemsolversbike.com/products/universal_derailleur_hanger). If you post a picture of the broken derailleur hanger, someone may be able to match it to a good generic (or you can do that yourself).

If the hanger is built into the frame and is just bent, you can use a crescent wrench to adjust it. If its built into the frame and broken off, time for a new frame (or if you're ambitious, you might be able to weld a new one on.

Comment: Hint:  When straightening a bent hanger, the thread that the derailer screws into is typically the same as a standard skewered axle.  Use an old axle and cone (thread in axle with cone on it, then tighten cone up against the hanger) to straighten the hanger, rather than directly applying the wrench.  This is much more controllable, and you have a good reference for "straight".